# Identical expressions in SymPy are not ==

Tags: python, sympy

I have two structurally identical expressions in SymPy, created in different ways:

```
import sympy as sp

f = sp.Symbol('f')
x = sp.Symbol('x')

by_hand = sp.Function(f)(x)
from_string = sp.sympify('f(x)')
```

Despite being identical expressions by construction, the two are not `==`:

```
by_hand == from_string
# False
```

Indeed, SymPy doesn't even know that they're equal **symbolically**:

```
sp.simplify(by_hand - from_string)
# ()−()
```

The two have identical `srepr`s:

```
(sp.srepr(by_hand), sp.srepr(from_string))
# ("Function('f')(Symbol('x'))", "Function('f')(Symbol('x'))")

sp.srepr(by_hand) == sp.srepr(from_string)
# True
```

I know that [round-tripping through strings isn't necessary reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50694693/85467) for maintaining identity in SymPy, but even using the `locals` argument as a fix doesn't resolve this issue:

```
by_hand == sp.sympify('f(x)', locals={'f': f}) == by_hand
# False
```

Having to use `locals` is already somewhat painful, because I am trying to do unit testing of a routine that constructs a bunch of symbolic expressions by constructing them independently.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to fix that.

### Fix 1

Pass `locals={'f': sp.Function(f)}` instead of `locals={'f': f}`.

```py
by_hand = sp.Function(f)(x)
from_string = sp.sympify('f(x)')

# by_hand == sp.sympify('f(x)', locals={'f': f})                     # Change this
by_hand == sp.sympify('f(x)', locals={'f': sp.Function(f)})  # True  # to this
```

You defined `by_hand = sp.Function(f)(x)`, so `Function('f')` in `sp.srepr(by_hand)` is `sp.Function(f)`, or `sp.Function(sp.Symbol('f'))`.

On the other hand, `Function('f')` in `sp.srepr(from_string)` is `sp.Function('f')`.
(This leads us to Fix 2.)

The difference is that `sp.Function(sp.Symbol('f'))` inherits the default assumption `{'commutative': True}` of `sp.Symbol('f')`.
(This leads us to Fix 3.)

### Fix 2

This is the clean fix and may be what you intended.

```py
# f = sp.Symbol('f')  # Change this
f = sp.Function('f')  # to this
x = sp.Symbol('x')

# by_hand = sp.Function(f)(x)  # Change this
by_hand = f(x)                 # to this
from_string = sp.sympify('f(x)')

by_hand == from_string  # True
```

### Fix 3

This hack demonstrates the inherited assumption `{'commutative': True}` identified in Fix 1.

```py
by_hand = sp.Function(f)(x)
del by_hand._kwargs['commutative']         # Add this
# del by_hand._assumptions['commutative']  # Add this, optional
from_string = sp.sympify('f(x)')

by_hand == from_string  # True
```